# How to pass info to directive when looping through Angular array?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using an array of objects to populate info in a directive, but I do not know, when looping through that array, how to insert each object in the array into the "info" parameter of my directive.

Basically, the HTML template uses data passed to it in the info parameter, like so:

```
<directive info="{{angular object}}"></directive>
```

I know how to do this when I've hard-coded individual objects in the controller, like so:

```
$scope.object1 = {...values here...}
$scope.object2 = {...values here...}
etc.
```

For this I use:

```
<directive info="object1"></directive>
<directive info="object2"></directive>
```

But when I'm looping, I can't do that because I need to repeat the directive for each object in the array.

Here's what i've got

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="card" ng-repeat="app in apps">
      <app-info info="{{app}}"></app-info> <!--HERE IS MY PROBLEM-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I have no idea how or what to put as a value for the "info" parameter.

My MainController is as follows:

```
 $scope.apps = [ 
  { 
    icon: 'img/move.jpg', 
    title: 'MOVE', 
    developer: 'MOVE, Inc.', 
    price: 0.99 
  }, 
   {
    icon: 'img/gameboard.jpg',
    title: 'Gameboard',
    developer: 'Armando P.',
    price: 1.99
  },
  {
    icon: 'img/forecast.jpg',
    title: 'Forecast',
    developer: 'Forecast',
    price: 1.99
  },
  { 
    icon: 'img/shutterbugg.jpg', 
    title: 'Shutterbugg', 
    developer: 'Chico Dusty', 
    price: 2.99 
  }];
```

The result is empty, meaning when I load the webpage, there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove brackets. You were close.

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="card" ng-repeat="app in apps">
      <app-info info="app"></app-info> <!--HERE IS NO PROBLEM-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```